# How can i avoid typing inputs manually codeblocks

Tags: input, codeblocks

I am a codeblocks user.I want to pass a set of input maybe from a file or as arguments so that i do not have to type long inputs manually.Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Project -> Set program's arguments
```

or if you want to redirect I/O:

[Code Blocks redirecting input output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295869/code-blocks-redirecting-input-output/26305888#26305888)