# CodeBlocks output file

Tags: c, output, codeblocks

I have a file that is called "Hello.c". There is a way to force CodeBlocks in order to create a file "Hello.txt" automatically where there is the output of my program?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13295869/4996248

Comment: If your using gcc execute program like this  ./main > “Hello.txt”